# Add custom view on top of other UITableViewCell's

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a tableView with cell and in a specific cell i want to add a view that is bigger that the cell and is is overlapping the other cell where i want to add buttons, labels and so on.

The problem is on scrolling and on touch. I tried `bringSubviewToFront:` and also set the `zPosition` to 3 and also i `setClipsToBounds:` to NO but as you can see in the hierarchy my custom views are under the cells.

My question is how to bring my custom view that are child of a custom cell in front of all cells and how to make all area to respond to touch events.

### [image: view hierarchy]

this is what i want to achieve, This happens only at the first start and gesture recognisers respond only over the parent cell.

[image: desire view hierarchy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable bounds clipping on your cell's view:

```
[cell setClipsToBounds:NO];
```

If the view that must overlap multiple cells is embedded in a subview, make sure that this subview has its `clipsToBounds` property set to `NO` too.

Comment: yes this is a solution but i end up using a scrollview and custom views ;)